# Frequent disconnects while busy running in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

In the last week or two I have seen frequent disconnects while trying to run a lengthy training run. A month or two ago this seemed to be working pretty reliably. My code has definitely changed but those internal details seem unrelated to the operation of Colab.

(On the other hand, I did switch my local machine from an Intel MacBook Pro running Big Sur to an M1 (Apple Silicon) MacBook Pro running Monterey. I assume that does not matter to Colab running in the cloud, via a Chrome browser.)

I see two kinds of disconnects:

1. There are “faux disconnects” which seem like false positives from
   the disconnect detector. These last less than a second, then the
   computation continues apparently unscathed. A black notification
   slides up from the lower left corner of then window, then slides
   back. See a link to a video of this below.
2. Then there are “real disconnects.” I start a computation that I
   expect to run for several hours. I see “faux disconnects” happen
   frequently. But less than an hour into the computation, I find
   the Colab window idle, no status information, and a **Reconnect** button
   in the upper right corner.

[Link to video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7Dv6EkA9qE) I started this session around 1:03 pm. This video was recorded at 1:35 pm. Normally the training session should have run for several hours. Instead it died at 1:52 pm (~50 minutes into the run). See some additional [comments](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2032#issuecomment-1200297659) in an issue at GitHub.

**Can anyone help me understand how to get past this? I am currently unable to make progress in my work because I cannot complete a training run before my Colab runtime decides to disconnect.**

**Edit:**

FYI: since once a “real disconnect” happens it is too late to look at the (no longer connected) runtime's log, and since this seems to run for about an hour before disconnecting, I saved a [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hnDvxBllQFiEei2EkssVfWyQdh0yay7z/view?usp=sharing) when a run was about 10 minutes in.

**Edit on August 1, 2022:**

My *real* problem is the “*real* disconnect” on my *real* Colab notebook. But my notebook is overly complicated, so not a good test case. I tried to make a small test case, see Colab notebook: [DisconnectTest.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19uFqBsjXsarSMrMsxRjG3Lq4SL1ZEOsR?usp=sharing). It contains a generic NIST-based Keras/TensorFlow benchmark from the innertubes. I made a [screen grab video](https://youtu.be/RTU0o6_onnM) of the first 2.5 minutes of a run. While this run completes OK — that is, there are no “real disconnects” — it had several “faux disconnects.” The first one is at 1:36. These seem fairly benign, but they do disrupt the Resources panel on the right. This makes it hard to know if the source of the “real disconnect” has anything to do with exhausting resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I described in a parallel post on [Colab's Issue #2965 on Github](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2965), this appears to be “some interaction between Colab and Chrome (and perhaps macOS Monterey (Version 12.5.1), and perhaps M1 Apple Silicon). Yet Colab seems to work fine on M1/Monterey/Safari.”

As described there, a trivial Colab example fails on Chrome browser but works fine on Safari.